# Basic rerouting in laravel

Tags: laravel, routes

So I have this route

```
Route::get('/locations/{lat}/{lng}', ['as'=>'locations.find', 'uses'=> 'LocationsController@find']);
```

and This takes me to the controller

```
public function Find($lat,$lng)
{


    $URLToCall = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=".$lat.",".$lng."&key=".self::$apiKey;
    // $URLToCall = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=".urlencode($placeName)."&key=".self::$apiKey;
    $result = json_decode(file_get_contents($URLToCall),true);
    if($result['status'] == "OK") {
        $URLToCall = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=".$result['results'][0]['place_id']."&key=".self::$apiKey;
        $result = json_decode(file_get_contents($URLToCall),true);
        // echo $URLToCall;
        // print_r($result);
        $googlePlaceData =  $result['result'];
        $place_id = $googlePlaceData['place_id'];
        $address = $googlePlaceData['name'];

        $name = $googlePlaceData['name'];
        $lat = $googlePlaceData['geometry']['location']['lat'];
        $lng = $googlePlaceData['geometry']['location']['lng'];
        $formatted_address = $googlePlaceData['formatted_address'];
        // echo $formatted_address;
        // dd($result['result']);
        $location = LocationRepository::get($place_id, $address);

        echo $location;
        // return response()->json(json_decode($location));
    } else {
        echo "Could not Find Data";
    }
}
}
```

Now when I add a new Location I get 
    Request Method:GET
    Status Code:500 Internal Server Error

But when I refresh the same Url I get the data the way I want it. 
the problem should be with the way I return data. But I cant figure out how am I supposed to get it down. The minute I add a new lat, lng which I don't have saved in my location database. I get this error.
Any help here will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You can check $location exist, if not create the new one before echo $location

Comment: Location is present in db. My location repository creates a location and returns a location. also if I check the db the location is created.

Comment: In your route you have mentioned LocationsController@find and in your controller public function Find() Find in different case

Comment: Turn on debug in .env and post what is happening w

Comment: debugging is on. I get no errors in laravel logs. low caps find does not seem to be the error. In any case i have changed it too...

Its weird. After refreshing the url, I get teh correct results.

Comment: Internal server error will through errors in your Webserver logs. Check Nginx/Apache logs for that.